# RegEx returns float number without precision

Tags: c#, regex

I have this text file

```
1   3          10.1144881901           48.8578515599          340.2980957031           -3.9997586182           -2.0398821492          -56.6352938643
2   1          10.1137751593           48.8575005060          401.4981384277          -11.7762306910            3.4075851669          -92.5498187137
```

And I have this C# code to read the numbers, I need the 5th column and change that value then save all columns to a new text file.

```
String pattern = @"(\d+)\t(\d+)\t\s+[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+\t\s+[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+\t\s+[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(line, pattern))
{                        
   string value = m.Groups[5].Value;
}
```

The value string contains only 340. instead of 340.2980957031
Very strange the m.Groups[0] contains all the numbers including the precision.

Comment: now it don't find any row

Comment: Use this for reference, you should be able to fix it easily: https://regex101.com/r/lD1wC7/31

Comment: thanks! I will try that

Comment: for such a simple case RegExes are overkill. Why not use `String.Split`? Much easier to write and read.

Answer (score 1):

What about that regex:

```
^([+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?\s+){4}(?<number>[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

[DEMO](http://goo.gl/Sh5y11)

You can access all numbers by

```
match.Groups["number"].Value
```

The pattern for decimal numbers is: `[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?` Because of the greediness of a regex it will catch all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, this expression includes the floating point precision

```
(\d+)\t(\d+)\t\s+[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\t\s+[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)\t\s+[-+]?([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)
```